# Beautiful Soup/Panada Table Parsing only parsing headers

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

So I am currently trying to write a discord bot but I need to scrape data from a website that has a table that refreshes every 5 mins. I am using python and to parse this particular table I am using requests, Beautiful Soup 4 and pandas. I was able to get the headers of the table to populate in spyder ide but for some reason the td items will not parse. Could someone put me in the right direction. that is the code I am dealing with

```
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')


#Page URL 

url = 'https://www.toronto.ca/toronto-fire-active-incidents/'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

soup 

#table fetching

table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'chart'})

headers = []

for i in table.find_all('th'):

  title = i.text
  headers.append(title)

  df = pd.DataFrame (columns = headers)

  for row in table.find_all('tbody')[1:]:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = row_data
```

Comment: Data inside table is generated from `javascript` to hard to extract from `bs4` so try with selenium

Answer (score 3):

You can get the event table data from the endpoint and then parse it.

All this can be done with pure `requests` and `bs4`.

Here's how:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    endpoint = "https://www.toronto.ca/data/fire/livecad.xml?i4sqso"
    header = [
        "Prime Street", "Cross Street", "Dispatch Time", "Incident Number",
        "Incident Type", "Alarm Level", "Area", "Dispatched Units"
    ]

    page = requests.get(endpoint).text
    events = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml").find_all("event")

    event_table = []
    for event in events:
        row = event.getText(separator="|").split("|")
        if len(row) == 7:
            row.insert(1, "")
        event_table.append(row)

    print(tabulate(event_table, headers=header))
```

Sample output (yours might be diffrent becasue events change):

```
Prime Street    Cross Street                Dispatch Time        Incident Number    Incident Type                 Alarm Level    Area  Dispatched Units
--------------  --------------------------  -------------------  -----------------  --------------------------  -------------  ------  ---------------------------
JARVIS ST, TT   DUNDAS ST E / GERRARD ST E  2021-05-12 03:12:04  F21044414          Alarm Highrise Residential              0     325  R325, P314, A325, C33, P313
M5A                                         2021-05-12 03:16:48  F21044415          MEDICAL                                 0     333  P333
M6L                                         2021-05-12 03:20:35  F21044416          MEDICAL                                 0     133  R133
```

Comment: Thanks but I noticed when there are alot of units responding it will move into the next row ruining the table how do I make it stay in one column in multiple lines